# Conexion SQL Server desde archivo xml

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

mi duda es la siguiente debo pasar mi cadena de conexion actual, que es esta:

```
   internal Clsconexion()
    {
        cadena = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConSicap"].ConnectionString;
    }
```

Pero me piden que la mejore y la pase a este formato de cadena nueva:

```
//******************************************************************
strArchivoXml = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("RutaXmlDatos"));
        // Obtiene la ruta de acceso del archivo ejecutable que inicia la seccion.

        try
        {
            objDocumento.Load(strArchivoXml);
            objNode = objDocumento.SelectSingleNode("//Servidor");
            strServidor = objNode.InnerText;
            objNode = objDocumento.SelectSingleNode("//Basedatos");
            strBaseDatos = objNode.InnerText;
            objNode = objDocumento.SelectSingleNode("//Usuario");
            strUsuario = objNode.InnerText;
            objNode = objDocumento.SelectSingleNode("//clave");
            strClave = objNode.InnerText;
            objNode = objDocumento.SelectSingleNode("//SeguridadIntegrada");
            strSeguridadIntegrada = objNode.InnerText;

            if (strSeguridadIntegrada == "Si")
            {
                strStringConexion = "Data Source=" + strServidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + strBaseDatos + "; Integrated Security = SSPI";
            }
            else
            {
                strStringConexion = "Data Source=" + strServidor + ";Initial Catalog=" + strBaseDatos + ";User Id =" + strUsuario + "; Password=" + strClave + ";";
            }

            objDocumento = null;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            strError = ex.Message;
            objDocumento = null;
            return false;
        }
```

Mi duda es como se debe crear el archivo `xml` que llamo desde mi `App.config`, que formato debería tener ya que nunca he trabajado con estas cadenas, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

De ante mano muchas gracias!

Comment: Por mi experiencia te diría que es mil veces mas practico que asignes la cadena de conexión directamente al app.config

Comment: Actualemente esta así: <add name="CnnSicaf" connectionString="Data Source=SRVSQL-PRUEBAS\SQL0.... Pero los de seguridad la quieren desde el xml, asi: <add key="rutaXml" value="C:\RutaXmlDatos.xml" />

Comment: No me refería a que lo pongas en código duro, sino que lo asignes de forma dinámica

Comment: No te comprendo la idea, me puedes regalar un ejemplo? porfavor

Comment: Esta bien pondré una respuesta en base a lo que yo hago para asignar la cadena de conexión directamente al app.config

Comment: yo considero que ahí no se está mejorando nada, es más fácil como la tienes originalmente

Comment: @shop350 Lo que se busca es que en ninguna parte del programa esten las credenciales e Ip del server de DB por eso lo quieren en un archivo fuera del codigo fuente. Tienes razón no es mejora, solo es control de seguridad

Comment: Mejor puedes sugerirles cifrar esa parte del config https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dtkwfdky.aspx#Anchor_2

Answer (score 0):

> Lo que se busca es que en ninguna parte del programa esten las credenciales e Ip del server de DB por eso lo quieren en un archivo fuera del codigo fuente.

Una opción es mover la sección de `connectionStrings` fuera del App.config a otro archivo de configuración, así puedes seguir usando `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` sin más complicación.

en App.config:

```
<!-- el resto de la configuración igual -->
<connectionStrings configSource="connections.config"/>
```

creamos otro archivo llamado "connections.config":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="test" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

este sería todo el contenido del archivo, solo puede tener la sección que va a reemplazar.

Por último, configurar para que cuando se compile el proyecto el archivo de configuración nuevo se copie a la misma carpeta para que funcione:

[image: Copy always]